# Why is TypeScript's `Partial` type allowing unspecified types as a valid value for a specified key?

Tags: typescript

```js
type Test = { a: string; b: boolean; c: number }
type Key = keyof Test;

function foo(x: Key): Partial<Test> {
  return {[x]: null};
}
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKhDOwoF4oG8oEMBcVECcBLAOwHMBuKAI1yoHs6AbCTYygY12IFcBbKiPigBfAFChIUANIQQKKAGtZdAGawEwcqNEruxdsEJ1iUFQwAUOabICUuAAqZ8hzIwA8cRAD50oqFHwIYG58EzQAbUwAXS5uRkZhLTEgA)

For the above code, `foo` returns a `Partial` of `Test`, and the key of the return object is bound to `Key`, `'a' | 'b' | 'c'`. However, even though the argument is the key of the `Test`, the `null` value is assignable for the `Partial<Test>`.

Is it intended behaviour for TypeScript?

Comment: This is not the problem of `Partial` type, in fact if you write `let test : Partial<Test> = {a: null}` it correctly gives you error. The problem here is `x` is unknown until runtime. So there is no way to resolve the type of `[x]` in compile time.

Comment: This is essentially [ms/TS#38663](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/38663); `{[x]: null}` gets its type widened to `{[x: string]: null}` which isn't *wrong* but it's kind of unhelpful, but then somehow *that* is allowed to be assignable to `Partial<Test>` which is a bug described at [ms/TS#27144](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27144). So part of this is definitely not intended behavior.  Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

This is not an answer per se since this issue seems more like a bug or an unimplemented feature in TypeScript than an issue in your code, but here are some workarounds to this issue:

1. Using the `satisfies` operator, we can ensure that the return type adheres to what we set:

```
function foo(x: Key): Partial<Test> {
  return { [x]: null satisfies Test[Key] }; // This checks whether 'null' is assignable to one of the values in 'Test' without changing the type of 'null'.
}
```

2. The type of `{ [x]: null }` is `{ [x: string]: null }`, so if we set the return type (or, create a variable and set its type) using a similar syntax, we once again get the correct error:

```
function foo(x: Key): { [x: string]: Test[Key] } {
  return { [x]: null };
}
```